# potentially dangerous Request

Tags: asp.net

I created web page where user can fill his detail.After clicking on button,user is redirected to another page.Suppose user enter something in address which include '<' or '>'I am changing it with it's htmlencode character through javascript onclientclick event of button to avoid error 'potentially dangerous Request'. and onclick event of button again,replacing htmlencode character to '<' or '>'.When user use browser's back button.He will see html encode character not '<' or '>'.Why this is happening,I already changed to '<' ?.How to handle this?I am using content page?I am using .net framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is designed to help prevent some script-injection attacks.

To disabling request validation for your application, Please set the validateRequest =false in web config file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please refer this link for more. 
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: ,thanks for ur reply.That work in framework 2.0.For framework 4.5, it will not handle...

Comment: Please add like this.
 <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>